# subl causing Floating point exception

Tags: assembly, x86

I am creating a compiler which should compile a fictional language into asm x86 code.

When compiling this piece of code (fictional code):

```
    int x;

int f(int n) {
  write n;
}

int main() {
  x = 1;
  f(x);
}
```

write is equal to just print in console.

The desired output is: 1

Which results in this assembly code:

```
.section .text
.include "print_int.s"
.globl _start
.type _start, @function
_start:
  call main
  movl $0, %ebx
  movl $1, %eax
  int $0x80

.globl f
.type f, @function
f:
  pushl %ebp 
  movl %esp, %ebp 
  .equ n, 8
  pushl n(%ebp)
  call print_int
  addl $4, %esp

.L1_f:
  movl %ebp, %esp 
  popl %ebp 
  ret

.globl main
.type main, @function
main:
  pushl %ebp 
  movl %esp, %ebp 
  .equ _tmp4, -4
  subl $16, %esp
  movl $1, x
  pushl x
  call f
  movl %eax, _tmp4(%ebp)
  addl $4, %esp

.L3_main:
  movl %ebp, %esp 
  popl %ebp 
  ret

.section .data


x: .int 1
```

print_int function:

```
# print an integer
.section .text
.globl print_int
.type print_int, @function
# print_it(int value) -- print value followed by \n to stdout.
print_int: 
    pushl %ebp 
    movl %esp, %ebp 
    .equ value, 8 # parameter offset
    # initialize local variables:
    .equ base, -4 
        pushl $10 # base = 10
    .equ bufsize, -8
    pushl $1 # bufsize = 1 ('\n')
    .equ negative, -12
    pushl $0 # negative = 0
    # stack: .. value return-addr saved-ebp base bufsize
    pushl $10 # push newline to be printed last
    movl value(%ebp), %eax 
        jge .L1 # if value >= 0
    # value < 0: remember
        movl $1, negative(%ebp)
    negl %eax # value = -value
.L1:
    cdq # setup %edx:%eax for division
        # aex = value/base, edx = value % base
    divl base(%ebp) 
    # push remainder digit 
    pushl %edx
    addl $48, (%esp)
    incl bufsize(%ebp) # ++bufsize
        cmpl $0, %eax
    jne .L1 # loop if value != 0
    # put sign if negative
    cmpl $0, negative(%ebp)
    je .L2
    pushl $45 # '-'
    incl bufsize(%ebp)
.L2:
        # write(2): eax = 4, ebx = fd, ecx = buffer start, edx = buffer size
    movl $4, %eax # code for write syscall
    movl $1, %ebx # fd stdout = 1
    movl %esp, %ecx # buffer start = top of stack
        movl $4, %edx # bufsize * 4 bytes
    imul bufsize(%ebp), %edx 
    int $0x80 # syscall
    movl %ebp, %esp
    popl %ebp # restore saved frame pointer 
    ret
```

The problem is when I try to run this code with this command (it runs on a 64 bit linux mint laptop):

```
as --32 simple-2.s -o simple.o && ld -m elf_i386 simple.o -o simple
```

I am getting an exception namely Floating point exception.
When I comment out the line subl $16, %esp, my code runs as expected.
Why is this line causing an exception?

Comment: `When I comment out the line subl $16, %esp`  that isn't even in the code ;) But assuming you comment out some stack operation, chances are you messed up stack alignment. Also you didn't show `print_int.s` and use a debugger to pinpoint the exact location of the fault.

Comment: What is `write n;` supposed to do ? I get the feeling you're not showing us the actual code here ?

Comment: I added the code of the print_Int function.@Jester I realize I made a typo the line subl $4, %esp, was meant to be subl $16, %esp. I changed it now. Can you advise me a debugger? I'm new to assembler I never used a debugger to code it.

Comment: @PaulR I expect it to print in the console the value of n.

Comment: Oh, OK - so this is not mean to be C code then - it's your fictional language ?

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. I edit it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subl $16, %esp` is a red herring. The actual issue is in `print_int`:

```
movl value(%ebp), %eax 
jge .L1 # if value >= 0
```

`movl` doesn't set flags. You are missing a `test %eax, %eax` or equivalent before the `jge`.

Learn to use a debugger. It would have pointed you right at the problem. Here is what I did:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
print_int () at test.s:28
28          divl base(%ebp)
```

Okay, so why could that be? Let's look at the dividend in `eax` and `edx`:

```
(gdb) p $eax
$1 = -1
(gdb) p $edx
$2 = -1
```

From here it was easy to spot the problem.